# How to fix this bubble sort program?

Tags: java, sorting, bubble-sort

```
package arraySort;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.*;

public class openFile {
    int x;
    static int i;
    static int[] myList = {100};

    public static void main(String[] args){
        try{
            File myFile = new File("arraySort.txt");
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(myFile);
            while(scan.hasNext()){                
                myList[i] = scan.nextInt();
                BubbleSort(myList);
                System.out.println(myList[i]);                                
         } 
         catch(IOException e){
             System.out.println("File not found!");
         }
    }
    public static void BubbleSort(int[] x){
        if (x[i] > x[i + 1]){
            int temp;
            temp = x[i];
            x[i] = x[i+1];
            x[i+1] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, I've been trying since 10:30. It's the thirt time I am doing programming.

Comment: just a little hint: this program is very wrong. The fix is more than just a couple of lines...

Comment: you can search stackoverflow before you post a question. For example, here are questions tagged as "bubble-sort": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bubble-sort

Comment: Any particular reason you are doing the sort in each iteration of the scanner?

Answer (score 6):

Rather than give you the answer outright, here are a couple of hints:

1. You don't have any loops in `BubbleSort()`.
2. You should only call `BubbleSort()` once, *after* you've read in all the numbers from the file. Meaning, move the call outside of the `while` loop.
3. You never increment the variable `i` so you're just overwriting `myList[0]` each time through your `while` loop.
4. Arrays are not resizable. If you try to assign to `myList[1]` or `myList[2]` you will get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` error. There are several ways to solve this--one is to change it from `int[] myList = {100}` to `ArrayList myList = new ArrayList()`. You can add numbers to it with `myList.add(number)` and look them up with `myList.get(i)`.

Answer (score 2):

Your program has several problems, not just related to the sorting part.

```
static int[] myList = {100};
```

This line defines `myList` as an array with size 1, containing the single element `100`. Then, your main loop is

```
while(scan.hasNext()) {
    myList[i] = scan.nextInt();
    BubbleSort(myList);
    System.out.println(myList[i]);
}
```

You do not increase `i` in this loop so you are just overwriting the single value in `myList` with whatever value you read from the file. And when your `Bubblesort` function tries to access `myList[i+1]`, it throws an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` because there is no element at index `i+1` (which equals `1`, since you don't increase `i`).

In general, and especially for a beginner, it is better to use `ArrayList` than a regular array. Also, you should fill in the array first and only after it has all the elements should you attempt to sort it. Finally, it is a better idea to make the variables local instead of class members. So that would make your `main` function something like

```
ArrayList myList = new ArrayList();
while(scan.hasNext()) {
    myList.append(scan.nextInt());
}
Bubblesort(myList);
```

And then change `Bubblesort` to take an `ArrayList`, and then you can also make the loop index `i` local to the `Bubblesort` method. After that is done, you can work on getting the bubble sort algorithm working. Remember to be careful with your array indices there so that you never access outside the bounds of the array.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/data/arrays/32arraybubblesort.html <- some bubble sort example for you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
 try{
    File myFile = new File("arraySort.txt");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(myFile);
    while(scan.hasNext()){                
        myList[i] = scan.nextInt();
        BubbleSort(myList);
        System.out.println(myList[i]);
 } 
 catch(IOException e){
     System.out.println("File not found!");
 }
```

to:

```
try{
    File myFile = new File("arraySort.txt");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(myFile);
    while(scan.hasNext()){                
        myList[i] = scan.nextInt();
 } 
 catch(IOException e){
     System.out.println("File not found!");
 }

 BubbleSort(myList);
 System.out.println(myList[i]);
```

}

Change sort method according to answer by [@Federico](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/data/arrays/32arraybubblesort.htm)